# Modifying generating functions to work for cases with distinct objects

Tags: generating-functions

> A committee is made of three people. If there are two men and three woman to choose from, how many committees have one man and two women?

Since there is exactly two distinct kinds of people, we must use two variable generating functions,

So the generating function for men is,

$$ M= \binom{2}{0} 1 + \binom{2}{1} x +  \binom{2}{2} x^2 = (1+x)^2 $$

and,

the generation function for women is

$$ W= \binom{3}{0} 1 + \binom{3}{1}  y + \binom{3}{2} y^2 + \binom {3}{3}y^3  = (1+y)^3$$

So, we need coefficient $ xy^2$ in the product $ MW$ however I'm getting the wrong answer. How would I change the method to work for this scenario?

Note: I know the regular method of doing this, I am just trying to generalize this generalizing function technique to more complicated problems. So it's the technique I want the discussion to be around not particularly the direct answer to the question

Edit: I now realized that this are the binomial expansion of $ (1+y)^3$ and $ (1+x)^2$. However, I wish to ask, how would I directly infer this? that these are the expansions?

Comment: This is serious overkill for this problem, but you might look at something like $(1+x)^2(1+y)^3$.

Comment: why that specifical product?

Comment: You get one copy of $(1+x)$ for each man and one copy of $(1+y)$ for each woman.

Comment: @PeterForeman I am trying to generalize the generating function for more complicated problems

Comment: @lulu why is my way of writing it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your method.  And, I should stress, this is not a problem that lends itself to generating functions.  It is much, much more natural to populate the male sector and female sector separately and then multiply.

Comment: In your method, what might $y^2$ mean?  It's not like a dice throw where the $2$ means that exactly two women are chose...you need to keep track of the various ways to get two women.

Comment: I know how to do it in the easy way as PeterForeman had previously stated. I agree, it's not a direct application and that is why I told modification of generating function method. In my method y^2 means 'two women' . More generally y^k means k number of women

Comment: Right, that doesn't make sense since there is nothing in your expression that tells me how many ways there are to choose two (or $k$) women.  Note that in $(1+y)^3=1+3y+3y^2+y^3$ there is $1$ way to choose $0$ women, $3$ ways to choose $1$, $3$ ways to choose $2$ and $1$ way to choose $3$.  The algebra correctly keeps the count for you.

Comment: good point, I think I found a small modification to account for that

Comment: oh wait it ended up in samething you wrote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110792/discussion-between-ddd4c4u-and-lulu).

Comment: Right.  $(1+y)^k$ encodes the binomial symbols as coefficients.  In other words, and unsurprisingly, this method secretly coincides with the other.

Comment: You might be interested in  Chapter 10.4 of the book "Foundations of combinatorics with applications" - it shows the basics of compositioning  generating functions when seen directly as an interpretation of combinatorial construction. There is a free online version of the chapter here: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/CombText/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems this question has been answered in the comments, I'll try to add something with an official answer.

If you have 2 men and 3 women to choose from, then you can list out all of the possible committees (with no restriction on how many members there are) with the generating function

$$(1+m)^2 (1+w)^3 .$$

This is because $(1+x)^n = \sum \binom{n}{i} x^i$, and so the coefficients count the number of ways to choose $i$ people from a group of size $n$. Then multiplying
$(1+x)^n(1+y)^m$ gives $\sum_{i,j} \binom{n}{i} \binom{m}{j} x^i y^j$, which counts the number of ways to choose $i$ from the first group and $j$ from the second.

Thus, in the generating function above, if you want the number of groups with 1 man and 2 women, you want the coefficient of $m^1 w^2$, which is $\binom{2}{1} \binom{3}{2}$, the correct answer.

To answer the question in your edit, how could someone have come up with this approach? In general, if you have generating functions $F(x) = \sum f_i x^i$ and $G(y) = \sum g_j y^j$ (note the variables are different!) the product $FG(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} f_i g_j x^i y^j$. This counts the number of ways to do have $i$ things from $F$ counted, and $j$ things from $G$ counted. Which is exactly what you want for this problem. All you need to realize afterwards is that $F$ and $G$ need to count the number of ways to choose some number of people from a group, but this is exactly the binomial formula.

This method is nice because it generalizes to a host of more complicated problems, which is what you were getting at in asking this at all. It's also entirely automatic. You could plug this product of polynomials into [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/), and know the answer to a slew of related problems almost instantly.

To whet your appetite, here is a not-so-obvious generalization of this technique:

Say you have a group $G$ acting on a set of objects $X$, and you want to compute the number of different objects up to $G$-symmetry. That is, you want to know $|X/G|$. A technique known as [Pólya-Redfield Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) lets you solve this problem in huge generality. The underlying idea, though, is exactly what you're doing here.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental principle is that when you multiply 'polynomial factors' you are basically asking a series of yes or no question.

For example (1+y)(1+y)(1+y) is like placing the three women in a line and asking yes or no to  the question "Will I invite this woman to the committee? " for woman in the line. As an example of directly interpreting the polynomial  multiplication from this idea, Consider multiplying the **'y'** from first factor into the **one** of second factor and then onto that multiplying **'y'** from the third factor. In plain English, this means to say "choose the first woman and don't choose the second woman and choose the third one" . So this decision making chain can be simply expressed as $ (1+y)^3$ , if we expand this ,  the coefficient of $ y^2$ is the ways we could have decided to take two women's. This principle similarly applies for the men case.

[refer this stack for more details](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7741300?noredirect=1)